# Sending RC4 encrypted data over UDP causes changes in decrypted plaintext

Tags: java, encryption, udp

I'm trying to send some data across a UDP connection using Java.

At the Client, I encrypt the data with an RC4 algorithm which returns a string. This string, I convert to a byte array and send it as a Datagram Packet.

However, at the Server, the decrypted plaintext gives a result similar to the original but with some differences.

The RC4 encryption program works fine when I run it independently and both Client and Server use the same source code so I really don't understand why this is happening.

Here's the code for the Client side:

```
import java.net.*; import javax.crypto.Cipher; import java.io.*; import java.security.*; import java.security.spec.*; import java.util.*; import java.util.Base64.*;  
 
class EchoClient 
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setSoTimeout(120000);
        
        //Encrypting and sending data
        System.out.print("Enter data: ");
        String password = sc.nextLine();
        String credentials = password;
        String encryptedCredentials = RC4.encryptRC4(credentials, "637443");
        byte encCred[] = encryptedCredentials.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket packetCred = new DatagramPacket(encCred,encCred.length,InetAddress.getByName(args[0]),1500);
        socket.send(packetCred);
        System.out.println("\nEncrypted Credentials sent");
        System.out.println("Plain: " + credentials);
        System.out.println("Encrypted data: " + encryptedCredentials);
    
    }
}
```

And here's the Server:

```
import java.net.*; import javax.crypto.Cipher; import java.io.*; import java.security.*; import java.security.spec.*; import java.util.*; import java.util.Base64.*;
 
class EchoServer 
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("Server running. Awaiting Connection Request...\n");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(1500);
        
        
        //Recieving Credentials
        DatagramPacket packetCred = new DatagramPacket(new byte[512],512);
        socket.receive(packetCred);
        String stringCred = new String(packetCred.getData(),0,packetCred.getLength());
        String decryptedCred = RC4.decryptRC4(stringCred, "637443");
        System.out.println("\nReceived Authentication Data");
        System.out.println("Bob at: "+new Date()+" "+packetCred.getAddress()+":"+packetCred.getPort()+"\nData: "+new String(packetCred.getData(),0,packetCred.getLength()));
        System.out.println("Decrypted Credentials: " + decryptedCred);
}
```

Here's the Client terminal output:

> Enter data: Hello there. How's it going? I'm doing fine; thanks.
>
> Setting up RC4...
>
> Starting RC4 encryption...
>
> Encryption Complete:
>
> Encrypted Credentials sent
>
> Plain: Hello there. How's it going? I'm doing fine; thanks.
>
> Encrypted data: ?d¥érSÿ?dNé?=P°?Whéá=Nù?H!)îërC??f@?ï<B¬?i?í!

And here's the Server terminal output:

> Server running. Awaiting Connection Request...
>
> Setting up RC4...
>
> Starting RC4 decryption...
>
> Decryption Complete:
>
> Received Authentication Data
>
> Bob at: Wed Jul 29 05:01:51 IST 2020 /127.0.0.1:54835
>
> Data: ?d¥érSÿ?dNé?=P°?Whéá=Nù?H!)îërC??f@?ï<B¬?i?í!
>
> Decrypted Credentials: Hello thÆre. How'Æ it goinÆ? I'm doÆng fine;
> thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `String` is not a container for binary data. Your decrypt method should have a byte array parameter, not a `String`. Why are you using RC4? It has been deprecated for years, and banned by the IETF for TLS in 2015.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. All regular crypto algorithms are based on byte arrays as source for INPUT and OUTPUT. Your RC4-methods do have inputs of String and returning  STRINGs as well. Please edit your question and show us the RC4-methods for encryption and decryption. I'm for sure that your problem is placed here as other comments/answers argue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem with string encoding. Never use `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding unless you're absolutely sure that both ends use the same platform encoding.

Everywhere (`RC4.decryptRC4()/RC4.encryptRC4()`, `new String()`, `String.getBytes()`) where you need to convert `byte[]/String` do this:

From `String` to `byte[]`: `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

From `byte[]` to `String`: `new String(byte[], int, int, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

It doesn't really matter if it's UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1, **as long as it is the same in both ends**.

Oh, as @MarquisofLorne said, please don't use RC4 unless its for educational purposes only.

Comment: This really helped. Thank you very much! I'll always use this next time I convert between byte array and string.

Comment: And yeah, I'm using RC4 for a network protocol assignment. Our teacher said he didn't care about the RC4 encryption, as long as it worked and the protocol was correct. Thanks again!